# Load a page but never show the URL

Tags: html, redirect

I have searched and searched and maybe im searching for the wrong thing but here is what I am trying to do:

A user goes to paypal, pays then via the paypal redirect it sends them back to mysite to fill out a form.  This form writes to a file on my site.  What i need to do is HIDE the url of the form so people can just skip paying on paypal and go directly to the site.

Step 1) User pays via paypal
Step 2) Paypal redirects them to www.mysite.com/something.html
Step 3) User fills out form  - Form sends data to a .keyfile on a secure folder

I need to make it so no one can ever see where paypal is redirecting them?
So is it possible to have the URL show when paypal does the rediect
(Paypal) www.mysite.com/something.html  but have it show www.mysite.com ?

Ive tried rewrites, ive tried the frame source thing, the issue is It still shows the sub folder...

So i have mysite.com/something pulling up mysite.com/somethingelse.html
issue is, they could just bookmark mysite.com/something and it would still work for the end user.

If i can have the url always show the base url, even if they bookmark it, it would be like bookmarking the www.mysite.com

Comment: What do you clearly want? You want mysite.com to display mysite.com/something.html

Comment: i want to redirect people from paypal to www.mysite.com/something.html

But i want it to show in the address bar www.mysite.com  That way they cannot bookmark the actual source page to go back whenever they want

Comment: You are looking for URL rewrite

Comment: is this something you can help me with?

Comment: RewriteRule ^test.html/?$ /mysite.com 

Is what i tried, but that just forces the site to load mysite.com

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.ca$
RewriteRule ^v/serialadd\.html$ :///mysite.ca?&%{QUERY_STRING}

when i do this, it just brings up a 404 error

Comment: _“I need to make it so no one can ever see where paypal is redirecting them?”_ - that’s impossible, the redirect happens in my browser, of course I can see which URLs are gone through in the process. You need to first of all let go of the nonsense notion that _“hiding”_ stuff would increase security - it doesn’t. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: So is there no way to keep a user from being able to access the .html page after they pay from paypal then?

Comment: If you don’t want people to access stuff they did not pay for - then you need to check whether they have paid, before you return said stuff to them.

Comment: well i was just trying to automate the process a littlebit... once they pay, they can submit there serial # and it autowrites to a file serial.key and then the script would allow there device to enter the area... just didnt want the ability to see the url ... currently people pay, then send a message with the serial and everything is done manually

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the user actually paid using the transactionId (send with the response from PayPal) and check if the payment was successful and if the transactionId actually exists with PayPal. And on your side you can check if the transaction has already been handled. If any of the above is false, you redirect them to another page (or show a message or whatever). And otherwise the request is valid and not from a bookmark.

Maybe this documentation will help you a bit? [GetTransactionDetails API Operation (NVP)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: well that sounds like the perfect solution, but im not sure how to do that?

Comment: I would suggest reading the API documentation: [Paypal Developers](https://developer.paypal.com/reference/). PayPal has some very clear documentation. Or if you already know the API, use the link in my answer.

Comment: You will need some sort of storage on your own website to store handled transaction ID's. So you know if a user is just trying to visit using an already used transaction ID. The transaction ID (I believe) is sent by PayPal with the request in the return URL.

Comment: never _ever_ rely on the referer to do whatever. The referer is set and sent by the browser, and can easily be modified. For the major browsers you can even find plugins to do this for you. This has serious security implications

Comment: @giorgio I know. It's just the first step. The second step (most crucial) is checking if the transaction ID is correct and valid and is not already handled. Of course the checking of the referrer is just to stop users from directly visiting a useless page (useless for them if the transaction id is checked).

Comment: why even bother? just shoo them away.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on why my answer is getting downvoted? Always ready to learn. My answer doesn't state that using the referrer is the right way. But checking the transaction id is. Maybe I just written it down unclearly? Or is it actually incorrect?

Comment: I updated my answer and removed the irrelevant referrer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following code in your `.htaccess` to define the internal redirect :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/something.html/$ http://example.com/
```

Comment: that did nothing... RedirectMatch 301 ^/addserial.html/$ http://mysite.ca